# R Data Wrangling for Emails

Tags: r, data-cleaning

Need Help! this is a work related project. I need to clean 16,000 emails... Expected to do by hand :( I need to find a away to pull the domain name from the email and place it into a new column, and parse the name into a new column as well, while still keeping the original email. The data is partially complete.

```
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)

Email.Address <- c('john.doe@abccorp.com','jdoe@cisco.com','johnd@widgetco.com')
First.Name <- c('John', 'JDoe','NA' )
Last.Name <- c('Doe','NA','NA')
Company <- c('NA','NA','NA')

data <- data.frame(Email.Address, First.Name, Last.Name, Company)
separate_DF <- data %>% separate(Email.Address, c("Company"), sep="@")
```

Comment: Please provide a *reproducible* example.

Comment: See `separate` in the `tidyr` package for splitting email address into two columns.

Comment: I will produce a better example shortly, I am work and do not have access to R

Comment: or `strsplit` in base R

Comment: What do you mean by "parse the name into a new column"?

Comment: My hope is to parse the front half of the email "john.doe@abccorp.com into  first, last, company. john doe abccorp. This is much harder as the email format may not contain a full first name. "jdoe"

Comment: @SJSU2013 indeed, that's more of a pure NLP task than a data processing one. It might be a good idea to edit this part out of the question since you aren't actually asking about that part. It will make it easier for future users to search and find what they want. Also, if you figure out a solution based on the comments, I'd encourage you to post it as an answer and accept that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
df  <-  data.frame(Email.Address, First.Name, Last.Name, Company, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Corp <- sapply(strsplit(sapply(strsplit(df$Email.Address,"@"),"[[",2),"[.]"),"[[",1)
F.Name <- sapply(strsplit(sapply(strsplit(df$Email.Address,"@"),"[[",1), "[.]"),"[[",1)
L.Name <- sapply(strsplit(sapply(strsplit(df$Email.Address,"@"),"[[",1),"[.]"),tail,n=1)
L.Name[L.Name == F.Name]    <-  NA
OUT <- data.frame(df$Email.Address, F.Name, L.Name, Corp)
df[df=="NA" |is.na(df)] <-  OUT[df=="NA" |is.na(df)]
df
```

the function `separate` from `tidyr` looks good too.

http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/

From the information you have given, this also works:

```
library(tidyr)

df  <-  data.frame(Email.Address, First.Name, Last.Name, Company)
df2 <-  separate(df, Email.Address, into = c("Name", "Corp"), sep = "@")
df2 <-  separate(df2, Name, into = c("F.Name", "L.Name"), sep = "[.]", extra = "drop")
df2 <-  separate(df2, Corp, into = c("Corp", "com"), sep = "[.]", extra = "drop")
```

Comment: It works great for the data posted. But I'm getting an error on my actual data. "Error in strsplit(df$Email.Address, "@") : non-character argument"

Comment: then try `as.character(df$Email.Address)`. it wont work with factors

Comment: Now i receive: Corp <- sapply(strsplit(sapply(strsplit(df@Email.Address,"@"),"[[",2),"[.]"),"[[",1)
Error in strsplit(df@Email.Address, "@") : 
  trying to get slot "Email.Address" from an object of a basic class ("character") with no slots

Comment: @SJSU2013 you've mistyped `df@Email.Address` instead of `df$Email.Address`

Comment: YES!!! The tidyr code worked like a charm. You saved me weekends worth of tedious work! I can't thank you enough!